# What's the best practice of merging commits in maintenance branch to master in Gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

Our project is using Gerrit for code review. Currently we're mainly working on master branch for next release and a maintenance branch.

I'm wondering what the best practice of merging commits in maintenance branch to master is. Do I have to push those commits already in maintenance branch one by one, and go through the code review process again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 basic options:

1. Cherry-pick your commits from maintenance to master, and push them through gerrit.  On my team, we generally are less thorough on those code reviews because they've already been reviewed once.  Generally a simple compile-check is sufficient.
2. Merge the maintenance branch with the master branch and push this merge commit to gerrit.  This is generally a better solution, especially if you want all of the changes in maintenance applied to master.

With merge commits, git can do a better job of showing you how the branches relate.  It has more meta data so future merges are easier.  The one downside to merge commits is that they aren't displayed that well in Gerrit currently, and generally developers have to look through the merge commit locally using git tools to truly understand what is going on.

Comment: If you use Eclipse, you can also try the Gerrit connector for Mylyn. It displays changes like Mylyn tasks, and there are buttons to fetch that change automatically. Makes working with Gerrit a lot easier and more comfortable.

Comment: I agree with you. The merging option is the better one, there is only one merge commit need be pushed to Gerrit for complying code review process. And another thing is allowing the specific users to push merge commit to Gerrit(refs/for/*) via the web interface of project configuration.